# Отображение структуры

Tags: javascript

У меня есть

```
<input type="text" class="myInput" oninput="myFunction()">
<p class="hint">function_name( string, number )</p>
```

Как мне отображать подсказку с момента ввода названия функции, до ввода символа `)`, как выделять **жирным текстом** текущий аргумент?

Например, strlen(**string**)

Comment: не совсем понятно как и где вы хотите ее отображать, если чтоб это работало как подсказка тебе, то используй WebStorm

Comment: У меня есть свой текстовый редактор, в нём нужно отображать структуру функции, которую я вызываю.